# plantuml: Right to left arrows, grouped components

Tags: plantuml

I have the following diagram:

```
@startuml
left to right direction

rectangle    Foo1
rectangle    Foo2
rectangle    Foo3

node Bar1
node Bar2
node Bar3

storage Baz1
storage Baz2
storage Baz3

Foo1 --> Bar2
Foo2 --> Bar1
Bar1 --> Baz3
Bar2 --> Baz1
@enduml
```

Where some components are orphaned and dont have arrows. see [here](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/POyn2iCm34LtdK8No21tBw53xs5grJMu5YZgqjD78YG4ui7yz_NHH_DYMUttxT3vRMY2skh7i3JbbpKP027og9tHtrE4BawwE3U08ONnaPKEbGxbuyL4SmtwqndI6JmNXJXDzsr1bEr44Dz64Ot0JWGpZ-9dhG00) It renders fine but the orphaned components are all listed at the first tier.

I want to modify it so that I would have my components arranged like this:

```
Foo1 -> Bar2 -> Baz1

Foo2 -> Bar1 -> Baz3

Foo3    Bar3    Baz2
```

update:

@albert [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653569/9199853) that we can use invisible arrows to get the effect we want. And it works.

What if however we had something like:

```
@startuml
left to right direction

rectangle    Foo1
rectangle    Foo3

node Bar1
node Bar2
node Bar3

storage Baz1
storage Baz2
storage Baz3

Foo1 --> Bar2
Bar1 --> Baz3
Bar2 --> Baz1
@enduml
```

we'd get something like this: [+](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/POv13i9024Ntd88BT35rRneNteCuE4uoGa9nu-c5g4sJiY3__Kz-W6LrCdyz1mo-ExgYzVPmhDtuvbq580L96umnLzLoS4u0efNnGbOsDMygujNLg2MzonxcFSHTrkCqdRy5iNwKOLf_Ah2mr7Zx0m00) I suppose we could add the following hidden arrows:

```
Foo1 -[#hidden]-> Bar1
Foo1 -[#hidden]-> Bar3
Bar2 -[#hidden]-> Baz2
```

and that would give us the [desired effect](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/RO-_2WCX38TtdoBG-GQlUpawz2LA1wcf9zW4SkdIfsz4F8IUW_o-Bt_4PTCW-daNL_2be0oIqweGi-1JCvDpDGHA1S7EZTd_cRDpn17X6iJlQTwJbJTb2QdIruymZs1zTJrCqwKjiAkJ5Qlgv7lh_RJc694URSOVwpuywFRwWXJjypy0) or in text-form:

```
Foo3   Bar1  Baz3
Foo1   Bar2  Baz1
       Bar3  Baz2
```

Would be great if we could add invisible components `FooH`, `BarH`. ie:

```
FooH -[#hidden]-> Bar1
FooH -[#hidden]-> Bar3
BarH -[#hidden]-> Baz2
```

ie we'd use hidden arrows for invisible components which would separate them from legitimate arrows. I can't however find an easy way of marking a component as invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one of the key point here will be the `[hidden]` for the arrow.
You would start using using something like:

```
@startuml
left to right direction

rectangle    Foo1
rectangle    Foo2
rectangle    Foo3

node Bar1
node Bar2
node Bar3

storage Baz1
storage Baz2
storage Baz3

Foo1 --> Bar2
Foo2 --> Bar1
Bar1 --> Baz3
Bar2 --> Baz1
Foo3 -[hidden]-> Bar3
Bar3 -[hidden]-> Baz2
@enduml
```

**edit**

When you want to hide a component like `Foo1` you can use e.g.

```
hide Foo1
```

Comment: beautiful. Now what if we missed one of the Foo -> Bar arrows but did have a Bar -> Baz arrow? add a hidden Foo? :thinking

Comment: I don't get what you mean with "Now what if we missed one of the Foo -> Bar arrows but did have a Bar -> Baz arrow?"

Comment: instead of the given arrows, what if we had only: `Foo1 --> Bar2
Bar1 --> Baz3
Bar2 --> Baz1` ie no Foo2 so simply making the arrow hidden wont cut it if there is no arrow there to begin with.

Comment: Can you add the example of what you want in the original question (or start a new question with a reference to this question), it it unclear for me at the moment.

Comment: have updated the post ^

Comment: I've just made a small remark in my answer, it was not 1-00% clear what you wanted to accomplish, but maybe it gives a good hint.

Comment: ah that looks good.